# TouchLocation object not working properly

Tags: c#, ios, xna, xamarin, monogame

I am trying to implement a press and release button functionality and am getting  a non-working result that I can't figure out why.

```
public class Button
{
    public TouchLocation oldTouch, currentTouch;

    public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        TouchCollection touchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState ();

        if (touchCollection.Count > 0) {
            currentTouch = touchCollection [0];

            if (currentTouch.Position.X > position.X && currentTouch.Position.X < position.X + width &&
               currentTouch.Position.Y > position.Y && currentTouch.Position.Y < position.Y + height) {

                if (currentTouch.State == TouchLocationState.Released && oldTouch.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed) {
                    buttonEvent.Invoke (this, new EventArgs ());
                }
            }
        }

        oldTouch = currentTouch;

    }
}
```

First of all when I assign the below object:

```
currentTouch = touchCollection [0];
```

I get

> "Incorrect number of types or arguments"

in red as the value in the locals debug window (no error, just red texted value).
It still however correctly passes through the position checking IF statement but it does not pass the `Pressed`/`Release` IF statement.  If I replace `currentTouch` with `touchCollection[0]` then everything works as expected.
Am I using/assigning the `TouchLocation` object incorrectly?
Or am I maybe just overlooking an easy mistake?

Answer (score 2):

I always use something like `touchCollection.Last()` or `touchCollection.First()` to get only one component of `TouchCollection`. Anyway I don't see any error in what you are doing there.

For your problem, I think you can't do only

```cs
oldTouch.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed
```

but you have to check:

```cs
oldTouch.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed || oldTouch.State == TouchLocationState.Moved
```

because you don't know how the last touch was detected by XNA.

And as a suggestion, why don't you use `Rectangle`s for your button's collider? In this way you can simply call:

```cs
Rectangle.Contains(new Point(int)currentTouch.Position.X, (int)currentTouch.Position.Y))
```

instead of doing that `if` statement.